# Find numpy.int_ in array of int_s using numba

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I am using numba (0.10.2-5-gda3e2bb-dirty)  to speed up my code. Now I am trying the following:

```
from numba import void, int_, double, jit
import numpy as np

@jit
class bla(object)

    @void
    def my_fun
    k = np.int_(1)
    f = np.int_(np.array([1, 2 , 3, 4, 5]))
    if k in f:
        do something
```

However numba appears to choke on the in command. If I type something like

```
if k == 1:
```

everything is fine. However with the in command numba won't compile. Any thoughts?

Btw: I am running python 2.7 and

```
numpy.version
```

returns

```
numpy-1.7.1-py2.7-linux-i686.egg
```

Thanks in advance!

Nick

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of basic issues with your code syntax (indentation, missing parentheses, etc.), but if I re-write it as follows, I an error message that `in` type comparisons are not implemented yet:

```
NumbaError: (see below)
--------------------- Numba Encountered Errors or Warnings ---------------------
Error <class '_ast.In'> comparisons not yet implemented
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

```
import numpy as np
from numba import void, int_, double, jit

@jit
class bla(object):
    @void()
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

    @void()
    def my_fun(self):
        self.x = 1
        k = np.int_(1)
        f = np.int_(np.array([1, 2 , 3, 4, 5]))
        if k in f:
            print 'aaa'
```

I had to throw in the `self.x` lines because numba seems to fail on compile with unused variables, including `self`.

Comment: Sorry about the missing parentheses, this was something I threw together for illustration purposes. In any case, I programmed around the problem in another way.

I see the error message too. I guess, we just have to be patient. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Verfblikje Just as a note, when you post a question, you should try to include runnable code that produces the error or problem that you are asking about.

Comment: Will do next time! Thanks for the help in any case!