# fix error: jit decorator takes exactly one argument, 4 given

Tags: python, class, decorator, jit, numba

I have the following class definition:

```
class GentleBoostC(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # do init stuff

    # add jit in order to speed up the code
    @jit 
    @void (float_[:,:],int_[:],int_)
    def train(self, X, y, H):
        # train do stuff
```

Then, in another file, I do this:

```
import GentleBoostC as gbc

# initialize the 2D array X_train, the 1D array y_train, and the integer boosting_rounds

gentlebooster = gbc.GentleBoostC()
gentlebooster.train(X_train,y_train,boosting_rounds)
```

But then I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\app\Documents\Python Scripts\gbc_classifier_train.py", line 53, in <module>
    gentlebooster.train(X_train,y_train,boosting_rounds)
TypeError: _jit_decorator() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)
```

I find decorators so confusing, and it wasn't until this error that I realized that the `jit` implementation uses decorators too! Or at least I'm guessing it does.

Comment: The line you show in the traceback doesn't appear in the code you posted.  Please make sure you're posting the same code that's generating the error (and include the full traceback).

Comment: Edited accordingly. In posting the question I just renamed the variables to shorter names.

Comment: What is the `@void` decorator you're using there?  I don't see that usage mentioned in the Numba docs.  Can you give a link to where you saw that usage?

Comment: Oh... actually I can't remember now... I was going through a number of tutorials and links and trying to understand how to put it altogether, it's possible I made a mistake. However, there is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526791/find-numpy-int-in-array-of-int-s-using-numba But when I do it the way this link is saying - I always get an error saying "unexpected indent" on the line that I define the train function.

Comment: Yes, but notice that that example uses `@jit` on the class as a whole, and only `@void` on the method.  Did you try that?

Comment: Yes, but whenever I try that I get "unexpected indent". I've re-written and properly indented all my code since, but I still get that error. So I'm trying to get it working the other way.

Comment: Is this relevant? http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.7/doc/pythonstuff.html And if I add @jit before the class, do all the class's functions get sped up too? Or is it necessary to put jit before the function that I want to speed up?

Comment: According to those docs, you put `jit` only before the class and not before the methods.  I assume that is supposed to accelerate all methods.  I don't know that much about Numba so I'm not totally sure.  Did you try it and see?

Comment: I've tried, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There are three problems here:

1) The latest Numba (version 0.14) does not support jitting classes or class methods (jitting classes was lost in the 0.12 refactor, but will probably be added back soon).

2) There is no void decorator (although it's possible this existed in a previous version - I don't remember).

3) The function signature isn't specified correctly in the jit decorator. It should be something like: @jit(void(float_[:,:], int_[:], int_)) for a function that takes a 2d float array, a 1d int array, and an int, and returns nothing. You could also specify it as a string: @jit('void(f4[:,:], i4[:], i4')